# clang accepts "static_cast<const int&>" using "explicit operator int() const", gcc/VS reject

Tags: c++11, gcc, clang, visual-studio-2017, static-cast

Given this c++11 code: (everything remains the same compiling as c++14 or c++17)

```
class typeSafe {
public:
   typeSafe(int tValue)
      : value(tValue) {
   }

   explicit operator int() const {
      return value;
   }
private:
   int value;
};

int main() {
   typeSafe x{5};
   typeSafe y{5};
   if(static_cast<const int&>(x) == static_cast<const int&>(y)) {

   }
}
```

The controversy is because the `static_cast` attempts converting to a `const int&`, but the explicit operator gives an `int`, not an `int&`.

clang 5.0.0 silently compiles it, with every warning turned on.

gcc rejects it, with:

```
typeSafe.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
typeSafe.cpp:17:32: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘typeSafe’ to type ‘const int&’
    if(static_cast<const int&>(x) == static_cast<const int&>(y)) {
                                ^

typeSafe.cpp:17:62: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘typeSafe’ to type ‘const int&’
    if(static_cast<const int&>(x) == static_cast<const int&>(y)) {
                                                              ^
```

Visual Studio 2017 15.5 Preview 2 rejects it, with:

```
typeSafe.cpp(17): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'typeSafe' to 'const int &'
  typeSafe.cpp(17): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'typeSafe' to 'const int'
  typeSafe.cpp(17): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Note if the `static_cast` attempts converting to an `int&`, then all 3 compilers reject it, with clang saying:

```
typeSafe.cpp:17:7: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'int' cannot
      bind to a value of unrelated type 'typeSafe'
   if(static_cast<int&>(x) == static_cast<int&>(y)) {
      ^                 ~
typeSafe.cpp:17:31: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'int' cannot
      bind to a value of unrelated type 'typeSafe'
   if(static_cast<int&>(x) == static_cast<int&>(y)) {
                              ^                 ~
```

So, who's right and who's wrong?

Comment: You cannot convert an rvalue to a `int&`, so that makes perfect sense.  Now, should explicitly casting to an lvalue const reference invoke convert to `int`?  I am uncertain.  You might, however, want to add a question to your question, because right now it is nothing but a series of statements.  ;)

Comment: @Yakk, I edited the question to remove the rvalue issue, since non-rvalues is what my actual usage is.  And, I edited it to add the last line of a question.  :-)

Comment: `explicit operator int() const {` that operator returns a prvalue.